# Not able to initialise h2o in python notebook from IBM watson

Tags: python, ibm-watson, h2o

Trying to run H2o AutoML from IBMwatson. But not able to connect to H2o cluster (using h2o.init(ip="127.0.0.1", port = 8080)

Able to perform in anaconda notebook installed in desktop PC.

Running H2o version 3.26 and Java version 1.8.

Please help me to understand, if this is the problem with port? Do I need to enable port? Or is this due to non-compatibility?

[Installing H2o](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywkye.jpg)

[h2o and java version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHJUR.jpg)

[H2o init and error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8pm3.jpg)

Comment: i suggest you include the actual output.

Comment: Attached the screenshots. That should be helpful.

Comment: If you look at the output, you'll see there are JVM stdout and JVM stderr files.  Look at them, and you may get some insight as to what is wrong.